# Color the set of integers with four colors

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, coloring

Show that one can color the set of integers with four colors: blue, red, yellow and purple, such that for any four numbers with the same colors $a, b, c, d$ (not necessarily distinct, not all four of them equals to zero) we have $3a - 2b \neq 2c - 3d$

My first idea was linking the problem with [Four color theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) but it doesn't seem to relate to the problem.
Then I tried to color the integers considering modulo $n$, but still failed in the case $a \equiv b \equiv c \equiv d \equiv 0 \pmod n$.
Any idea?

Comment: $3(a+d)\neq2(b+c).$

Comment: Can you please tell me something less obvious?

Comment: Please clarify what coloring means here.

Comment: It means that we color every integer with one of four colors, for example 1 is blue, 2 is red, 3 is yellow, 4 is purple etc.

Comment: It looks like this question fits into the framework of Ramsey sequences on the integers. For example, there is a theorem of Rado which implies that there is a coloring with a finite number of colors that satisfies your conditions.